# Is this generalized factorization of a difference of powers correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, sums-of-squares, perfect-powers

Is this factorization true?

$$(x^n - y^n) = (x+y)^{n-1}(x-y)^{n-1}$$

I am trying to use it in my computation of the determinant of a Vandermonde matrix.

Thanks,

Comment: $x = 2, y = 1, n = 3$

Comment: got it -- nice counter-example, @SimonS, thanks so much :-)

Comment: Hi @SimonS, would there be at least some guarantee that factors of order 1, namely (x-y) and (x+y) exist on the R.H.S.?

Comment: @LebronJames yes. Namely: $x^n - y^n = (x-y)\sum_{i=1}^n x^{n-i} y^{i-1}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative (true) identity is

$$x^n - y^n = (x-y)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}y + x^{n-3}y^2 + \cdots + xy^{n-2} + y^{n-1})$$

Comment: Ok, got it - thanks so much @SimonS :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can't have equality in your equation since the LHS is degree $n$ while the RHS is degree $2n-2$.  These are only equal for $n=2$. The correct factorization is:

$$\begin{align}x^n-y^n & =(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+\cdots+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})\\
& =(x-y)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^{n-1-k}y^k.
\end{align}$$

Comment: ok, got it - thanks so much @TimRaczkowski :-)

Comment: Glad to help. :)